# No parameterless constructor defined for this object - asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3o8iuoDMyI&t=371s&ab_channel=C%23CodeAcademy

So I was following this guide but came across the problem of "No parameterless constructor defined for this object".

The solutions that I've been seeing is that I need to use a dependency injection, but I'm still struggling to understand it.

This is my code:

//HomeController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Judging_System.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Judging_System.Controllers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;






namespace Judging_System.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        List<Events> events = new List<Events>();

        // GET: Home

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            con.ConnectionString = Judging_System.Properties.Resources.ConnectionString;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

 
        private void FetchData()
        {
            if(events.Count > 0)
            {
                events.Clear();
            }
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                com.Connection = con;
                com.CommandText = "Select top (1000) [Id], [Event], [Venue], [Date], [Time] from [tbl_Events].[Id]";
                dr = com.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    events.Add(new Events() { Id = dr["Id"].ToString(),
                         Event = dr["Event"].ToString()
                        ,Venue = dr["Venue"].ToString()
                        ,Date = dr["Date"].ToString()
                        ,Time = dr["Time"].ToString()
                        });
                }
                con.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Contestants()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Latest_Events()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Past_Events()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Calendar()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Reports()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //Under Maintenance

        public ActionResult User_Account()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Events(Events events)
        {
            
            FetchData();
            con.Open();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = "select * from tbl_Events where Id='" + events.Id + "'and Event='" + events.Event +
                "'and Venue='"+ events.Venue + "'and Date='" + events.Date + "'and Time='" + events.Time +"'";
            dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            return View(events);
        }

        public ActionResult Criteria_For_Judging()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Judges()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Participants()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Pointing_System()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

//Events.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Events";
    Layout = "~/Views/_HomeLayoutPage.cshtml";
    string[] TableHeaders = new string[] { "Id", "Events", "Venue", "Date", "Time" };
}

<div class="table">
    <table class="table table-bordered  table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @{
                    foreach (var head in TableHeaders)
                    {
                        <th>
                            @head
                        </th>
                    }
                }

            </tr>

        </thead>



        <tbody>
            @{
                if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach (var Data in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Data.Event</td>
                            <td>@Data.Venue</td>
                            <td>@Data.Date</td>
                            <td>@Data.Time</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/aspnet-core-logging

Comment: *I need to use a dependency injection, but I'm still struggling to understand it.* - DI is not complex; you've been doing it for years with `class Person{ string _name; Person(string name) { _name = name; } }` - the Person class has a dependency on a string name, which must be provided, which you did with `var p = new Person("John")`. The only thing to get your head around is that *it's not you* that provides the name; it's now a magic black box that you tell "Every time something needs an X, give it one of these ...", with rules over whether the magic box should reuse an existing one or a new